# Ubuntu wont dual-boot on a Lenovo G505s

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu from a LiveCD next to Windows 7 in the following way:

Windows had 3 primary partitions, so I had to create a 4th extended one, under which I created:

- 1 / partition
- 1 swap partition
- 1 /home partition

Boot was set to legacy due to Win 7 being installed. Shortly before installation I changed even boot priority to Legacy first.

Installation went smooth, except for now when I'm greeted by GRUB and select I want to boot Ubuntu nothing happens. Nothing happens after selecting recovery boot for Ubuntu either.

**Update #1:**

I tried to change the boot priority settings in BIOS to EFI first, to no avail, although it seemed it would work. After installation and reboot the Windows entry was completely missing from GRUB, so I did Boot Repair while booted into the system, restarted, it worked once, got me to the desktop, installed updates, rebooted, didn't work again. What it did was it created another Windows entry on /dev/sda2, so now I have a duplicate.

Tried Boot Repair even from a LiveCD, to no avail.

**Update #2:**

Providing logs, please see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2275428

**Update #3:**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ inxi -F
Resuming in non X mode: glxinfo not found. For package install advice run: inxi --recommends
System:    Host: ubuntu Kernel: 3.16.0-30-generic x86_64 (64 bit)
           Desktop: Unity 7.2.4  Distro: Ubuntu 14.04 trusty
Machine:   System: LENOVO product: 20255 v: Lenovo G505s
           Mobo: LENOVO model: Lenovo G505s v: 00000000Not Defined
           Bios: LENOVO v: 83CN12WW(V1.01) date: 04/23/2013
CPU:       Quad core AMD A8-4500M APU with Radeon HD Graphics (-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB 
           clock speeds: max: 1900 MHz 1: 1400 MHz 2: 1400 MHz 3: 1400 MHz
           4: 1400 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7640G]
           Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Sun PRO [Radeon HD 8570A/8570M]
           Display Server: X.org 1.16.0 drivers: ati,radeon (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 80x24
Audio:     Card-1 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-2 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Trinity HDMI Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k3.16.0-30-generic
Network:   Card-1: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet driver: alx
           Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
           driver: ath9k
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1008.1GB (2.1% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST1000LM024_HN size: 1000.2GB
           ID-2: USB /dev/sdb model: DataTraveler_108 size: 7.9GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 3.5G used: 95M (3%) fs: overlayfs dev: N/A
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 20.97GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda6
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   None detected - is lm-sensors installed and configured?
Info:      Processes: 197 Uptime: 10 min Memory: 688.8/7105.6MB
           Init: Upstart runlevel: 2 Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.2.19
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the "nothing happens" part?  Do you get a blank screen?  A text screen with some text?  A splash screen that never goes away?  A grub menu that never goes away even if you press Enter on the Ubuntu entry?

Comment: After I choose to run Ubuntu the screen remains blank (dark purple), and stays like that. No flickering, nothing.

Comment: Okay!  And what happens if you pick 'recovery mode' from the Grub menu?

Comment: Nothing, the screen just goes blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved after I re-installed the whole computer and changed all BIOS settings to legacy mode. Now both Windows and Ubuntu boot fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked UEFI matter?
If BIOS boots in EFI mode, you may need to sure that Ubuntu install process takes it in account.

ubuntuforums.org may be a better site to solve this issue.

Comment: I switched BIOS to legacy mode before, so it should. After this occurred I even went back to BIOS and switched to EFI first to see if it would boot it, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with windows 7 once. I would try when you enter the windows 7 hold down F8 and enter your windows admin password. you then have to rebuild the windows boot loader. Then you have to reinstall grub using the ubuntu live cd. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Can you be more specific? When I enter Windows means when I'm presented with the desktop and icons, or when it's loading Windows (the boot screen with the logo)?

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu onto flash drive, change boot options to: Dvd/CDRom, USB, HDD. This is an easy dual boot, recommend flash drive 32gb or more.